# Pass list as parameter from repository to controller in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need to take a list that is filled in the repository layer to the controller layer without modifying the service, which already returns a DTO, so the idea is to pass the list as a parameter to the controller through the service layer.

the flow is controller -> service -> repo so i have to pass the list which is created in repo to the controller.

repo.cs

```
public ListDTO Register(RegisterDTO newProduct)
{
   List<NewListDTO> NewList = new List<NewListDTO>();
   NewList.Add(field); // pass list to controller

   return new ListDTO{
       field1,
       field2
   }
}
```

service.cs

```
public ListDTO Register(RegisterDTO newProduct)
{
   return unit.Repository.Register(newProduct);
}
```

controller.cs

```
public ListDTO Register(RegisterDTO newProduct)
{
   var response = service.Register(newProduct);
   //here would go the list that comes from the repo
   return response;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I don't understand what you want through your code... `service` and `repo` have the same `method name, return value and parameter`, and `service` also use the method in `repo`? you need to describe the question more clearly

Comment: Your register-method is not returning a List but a single Type. I would expect to see something like public List<SomeDto> Register(...) { ...}